# Retrieve Array value from JSOn to android client Array

Tags: android, arrays, json

i am doing now retrieving JSON array and assigning it to Android Array String but it failed. 
My integer "success" already well. Please help, thank you very much.

My JSON information:

```
{
    "details": [
        {
            "phone": "89898999",
            "name": "Maria"
        },
        {
            "phone": "98983555",
            "name": "John"
        },
        {
            "phone": "96969677",
            "name": "Leo"
        },
        {
            "phone": "97320099",
            "name": "Helen"
        },
        {
            "phone": "90063379",
            "name": "Judy"
        }
    ],
    "success": 1
}
```

Android code:

```
     String[] titleArray2;
        String[] descriptionArray2;
int cs = 0;
    .....
                    // Create a JSON object from the request response
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                    //Retrieve the data from the JSON object
            cs = jsonObject.getInt("success")
            JSONArray ja = jsonObject.getJSONArray("details"); 

            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) 
            {

                    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                    titleArray2[i] = jo.getString("phone");
                    descriptionArray2[i] = jo.getString("name");

            }
```

Comment: JSONArray ja =new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("details"));

Comment: Still retrieve error :(

Comment: Initialise your string array : String[] titleArray2 =new String[ja.size];

Comment: Oh ya, forgot to refine again arrays. Tks dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine, Just try initializing your array
Try like this

```
JSONArray ja = jsonObject.getJSONArray("details"); 
titleArray2 =new String[ja.size];
descriptionArray2[i]=new String[ja.size];
```

and then your `for loop`.

Mark as right if it works for you. :)